# Use adapter-node (SvelteKit) to create middleware for Express server

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, sveltekit

I'm attempting to implement a SvelteKit front-end onto my existing Express server, that handles auth and such.

I'm using the node adapter and trying to connect it to my Express app as middleware, with

`app.use(assetsMiddleware, prerenderedMiddleware, kitMiddleware);`

and importing from

`const { assetsMiddleware, prerenderedMiddleware, kitMiddleware } = "./client/build/middlewares.js";`

but I get the error

`TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined`

which leads me to believe it's not importing the modules correctly and the three imports are all undefined, though I can see in the middlewares.js file the exports are correct. I tried ES6 modules but no success with that, plus I prefer to stick to commonJS with Express.
I can't find any repos or tutorials on using the node adapter this way, and the docs are sparce.

Essentially, what is the fix for this error? I would also appreciate any resources that may help get SK as middleware in Express working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have forgotten to `require()` `"./client/build/middlewares.js";`. Object destructure a string (ie `const { x, y } = "Some String"`) makes the variables `undefined`. So to `app.use()` your actually passing three variables that equal undefined (ie `assetsMiddleware === undefined`). Thats why it gives a `TypeError`.

So the change you need to make is this:

```js
const { assetsMiddleware, prerenderedMiddleware, kitMiddleware } = require("./client/build/middlewares.js");
```

I hope this fixes it for you!

Comment: Now I am getting this error `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: ...\build\middlewares.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.`
Without switching to ES6 imports, how can I solve this one?

Comment: To add, I have adjusted the svelte.config.js settings to include something like this
`esbuild(defaultOptions) {
  return {
    ...defaultOptions,
    format: "cjs",
    plugins: [],
  };
},`
However I'm getting the same error still. (Apologies for the formatting!)

Comment: @Max It should work on the default config. The adapter [docs](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/master/packages/adapter-node/README.md) includes example code (just switch polka to express). You should also make sure you are on the latest version of the adapter (`npm I @sveltejs/adapter-node@next`). It never hurts to generate an example project using the cli in another dir to copy its config (make sure to change it to `adapter-node`). Hope this helps!

Comment: I got it working... It took a while to switch everything to ES6 modules but I figured it was for the best. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Max how do you make svelte to produce ES6 modules...i have been googling around without any success

Comment: @slier Svelte already produces ES6 modules using the node adapter. If your node.js project uses cjs, it needs to be changed to ES6.